# How to Update iOS Apps to Fit Larger Screen Size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I know this question might sound ridiculous, but please finish reading this thread before marking this as a duplicate question. 
I've been searching for answers throughout the internet but can't seem to find a satisfying explanation & solution as I'm not very sure how things work & how to make a change.

[Click me for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYaTR.png)
In the image, the app on the left is 'un-optimized' and stretched while the app on right is 'optimized' and perfectly fit.

So how do I 'optimize' an old app to fit on larger screens, given: 
• The app is built using Objective-C 
• Some screens only have header(.h) & method(.m) files, meaning there is no XML Interface Builder(.XIB) files to see how the UI looks like without running it on the device.

I've tried using size classes for screens with.XIB files, but regardless of that, the app still appears to be stretched. Also, what about those that only have header & method files? Since there is no interface builder, I couldn't modify the UI in terms of size classes & constraints.

Is there a universal setting or something that I need to change and the whole app will be magically 'optimized'? Or do I have to configure a certain setting for each screen one by one? 
Could someone explain to me in simple terms how this can be done?

Comment: Did you provide a launch image or launch XIB for each size you want to support?

Comment: Launch images in the **Images.Xcassets** folder? Yes.

Comment: Not sure if it's related or not. The image you have provided has nothing to do with the app being stretched. Instead, it is just a display zoom option provided by iOS. the image on the right is normal while the one on the left is zoomed. This setting can be toggled to on/off from Settings app

Comment: @Malik, the screenshot is just a simulation. My apologies if this confused you. 
My current app always appears as zoomed (and only when in the app) even though the system setting is set to Standard, if I had just posted a single image of the app, people might not be able to notice the zoom difference.

Comment: No. (Tried adding constraints, the entire web view disappeared instead)